# How to logging to different log files by using for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, logging, paramiko

I am writing python script which establish ssh connection using paramiko and receive response of executed different commands on different NE and write logs for each NE in different log file. I am using below code in which i have defined logger main function and writing log to other function within same class. It is working fine while writing single log file. Please let me know how to write different log file for different NE.

**CODE:**

```
def main(self):
    
    global logger
        
    with open(self.hostfile, 'r') as ip:
        ip_list = ip.read().splitlines()
        for host in ip_list:
            filename = "connection_debug-{0}.log".format(host)
            print('filename is:', filename)
            logging.basicConfig(filename=filename,
                                format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                                filemode='w')
            logger = logging.getLogger()
            logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
                    
                    
def send_to_ne(self, command, prompt):
        channel.send('%s \n' % command)
        while not channel.recv_ready():
            time.sleep(2)
        #self.get_channel_ready()
        global response
        response = " "
        while not response.endswith(prompt):
            received_result = channel.recv(9999)
            logger.debug(received_result.decode())
            #self.logging_func(received_result, host)
            received_result = str(received_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of above asked question

```
def debug_file(self, debugfile):
        global logger
        logger = logging.getLogger(debugfile)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
        debug = logging.FileHandler(debugfile, mode='w')
        debug.setFormatter(log_format)
        logger.addHandler(debug)

debugfile = "connection_debug-{0}.log".format(host)
self.debug_file(debugfile)
```